# How to make my Java JSONArray nested and add fields?

Tags: java, json, grails, jdbc, groovy

Sorry, possible newbie question, I'm trying to learn Java while contributing to a project at work. Actually code is Groovy (& we're using Grails) but assume that's the same for this purpose.

I'm trying to convert a JDBC ResultSet to JSON (to send to the front end). Got the following code from a blog:

```
// Convert JDBC ResultSet to JSON string
public static JSONArray convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet)
        throws Exception {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData(); // Result set meta data
    int total_columns = metaData.getColumnCount(); // Number of columns in the row

    while (resultSet.next()) { // Take each row from the result set
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_columns; i++) {
            obj.put(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
        }
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    return jsonArray.toString(); // Return as JSON string
}
```

This (I believe) will give me a JSON structure with the data in the root/top of the JSON. I want to move it into a sub-field (called e.g. 'data') and then have another couple of key/value pairs at root level. How would I modify the code to do this please? (I could pass the couple of extra values in as params)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JsonObject();
rootObject.put("data", jsonArray);
```

This will let you treat your JSON like a key-value pair and should accomplish what you are asking.

Additionally, you may want to look at using an `ObjectMapper` to convert your object to JSON. This would allow you to create a JSONObject from a Java object with something like `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resultSet)`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in the code snippet you provided, since your signature states `JSONArray` as a return type but you return a `String`, anyway here is what I would suggest:

```
public static JSONObject convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet)
        throws Exception {
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    root.put("data", jsonArray);
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData(); // Result set meta data
    int total_columns = metaData.getColumnCount(); // Number of columns in the row

    while (resultSet.next()) { // Take each row from the result set
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_columns; i++) {
            obj.put(metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                    .toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
        }
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Great thanks @Ilya, looks good. I didn't realise a JSONObject could return a JSONArray. Presume I can use root.toString() to get the complete JSON string to send to the front end? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `toString` to convert the object to json string.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a Groovy question, you could make your code more Groovy ;-)

```
static String convertToJSON(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
    def metaData = resultSet.metaData // Result set meta data
    def result = []
    while (resultSet.next()) { // Take each row from the result set
        result << (1..metaData.columnCount).collectEntries {
            [metaData.getColumnLabel(it).toLowerCase(), resultSet.getObject(it)]
        }
    }
    return new JsonBuilder(result).toString() // Return as JSON string
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the (it) reference though? And how would I have the resultset data in a sub section of the JSON and another couple of key/value pairs in the root? Thanks

Comment: `it` is the counter from 1 to the number of columns, and you could do `new JsonBuilder([a: 1, b: 'tim', items: result]).toString()`